# SQL query to get total amount from 2 table and sort by date

Tags: sql

I got a table for sales order and purchase order.

Sales order

```
Date   Amount

 26/10  120
 26/10  130 
 26/10  50
 27/10  50 
 27/10  60
```

Purchase Order

```
Date   Amount

 26/10  200 
 26/10  300 
 26/10  100
 27/10  100 
 27/10  100
```

I want to display the total sales and total purchase by date.

E.g.

```
 Date   Total Sales Total Purchases 
  26/10    300            600 
  27/10    110            200
```

My SQL query is like this but it doesnt work.

```
$query = "Select o.date, o.Amount AS Sales, p.date, p.Amount AS Purchases
          From customerorder o
          right join Purchaseorder p on o.date = p.date
          order by o.date";
```

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: You haven't added together the number of purchases. Sum them.

Comment: @JackManey If i do this:SELECT o.date, SUM( o.Amount ) AS Sales, p.date, Sum( p.Amount ) AS Purchases
FROM customerorder o
RIGHT JOIN Purchaseorder p ON o.date = p.date
ORDER BY o.date. It adds everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT COALESCE(o.date, p.date) date, Sales, Purchases
      FROM (SELECT date, SUM(amount) Sales FROM CustomerOrder GROUP BY date) o
 FULL JOIN (SELECT date, SUM(amount) Purchases FROM PurchaseOrder GROUP BY date) p
        ON o.date = p.date
  ORDER BY date
```

MySQL doesn't support FULL JOIN, so specifically for MySQL, you can use

```
    SELECT o.date, Sales, Purchases
      FROM (SELECT date, SUM(amount) Sales FROM CustomerOrder GROUP BY date) o
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT date, SUM(amount) Purchases FROM PurchaseOrder GROUP BY date) p
        ON o.date = p.date
 UNION ALL
    SELECT date, NULL, SUM(amount) Purchases
      FROM PurchaseOrder p2
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                       FROM CustomerOrder o2
                       WHERE o2.date = p2.date)
  GROUP BY date
  ORDER BY date
```

Comment: o and p is grouped, why u need to group again?

Comment: They're subqueries.  They're each run individually and are treated as pseudotables by the main query.  They don't affect the main query at all.  Note that you could also `COALESCE` your Sales and Purchases fields to zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.date,total_sales,total_purchase from 
(select date,sum(amount) total_sales from customerorder group by date) c
join
(select date,sum(amount) total_purchase from purchaseorder group by date) p
on c.date=p.date
order by c.date
```

I don't know the schema, so u may what to change "join" to "right join"